# Not able to insert data into postgre using spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

i am trying to insert data into my postgre table called question. I am trying to insert the data using post method through postman but only the id value gets inserted as it is autogenerated, other values in the table are being shown as null
my main class

```
package com.infosys;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class QuesMicroApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(QuesMicroApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

my controller class

```
package com.infosys.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.infosys.entity.Question;
import com.infosys.service.QuestionService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/question")
public class QuestionController {
    
    @Autowired
    private QuestionService qService;
    
    @PostMapping
    private Question create(@RequestBody Question question) {
        return qService.add(question);
    }
    
    @GetMapping
    private List<Question> get() {
        return qService.get();
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    private Question getOne(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return qService.get(id);
    }

}
```

my entity class

```
package com.infosys.entity;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "questions")
public class Question {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "question_id")
    private Long questionId;
    @Column(name = "question")
    private String question;
    @Column(name = "quiz_id")
    private Long quizId;

}
```

repository interface

```
package com.infosys.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import com.infosys.entity.Question;

public interface QuestionRepository extends JpaRepository<Question, Long>{

}
```

service interface

```
package com.infosys.service;

import java.util.List;

import com.infosys.entity.Question;

public interface QuestionService {
    Question add(Question question);
    List<Question> get();
    Question get(Long id);

}
```

service impl class

```
package com.infosys.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.infosys.entity.Question;
import com.infosys.repository.QuestionRepository;

@Service
public class QuestionServiceImpl implements QuestionService{

    @Autowired
    QuestionRepository qRepository;
    
    @Override
    public Question add(Question question) {
        
        return qRepository.save(question);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Question> get() {
        return qRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public Question get(Long id) {
        return qRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(()->new RuntimeException("Question not found"));
    }

}
```

application.properties

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/micro_zt
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true

server.port = 8080
```

i have also added the necessary dependencies in pom.xml

i have also added the necessary dependencies in pom.xml

Comment: Stop using entity class in your REST- API. Learn about 3tier architecture

Comment: @Jens i have just started learning about spring boot, rest and microservices, so dont have a lot of idea

Comment: You donot have any getter and setter on your entity object. Try to add them

Comment: @Jens thank you so much, i dont know how i missed that, i generally use the Data annotation from lombok so i thought i had added it

Comment: should i delete my question? or let it be?